# Automatic row numbers (after filtering DT in shiny)

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I would like to get the `rownames` count start again from 1,2,3... after filtering the datatable. Is it possible?

Here is simple code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)

x <- as.numeric(1:1000)
y <- as.numeric(1:1000)
data <- data.frame(x,y)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(dataTableOutput('tbl'),
                 plotOutput('plot1')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = renderDataTable({
      datatable(data, filter = "top", rownames=TRUE,options = list(
        pageLength = 300, lengthMenu = c(100,200,300,400,500,600)
      ))
    })
    output$plot1 = renderPlot({
      filtered_data <- input$tbl_rows_all
      ggplot(data = data[filtered_data, ], aes(x = x,y = y)) + geom_line()
    })
  }
)
```

So as an example if i filter column x to get the values from 50-..., I would like the `rownames` to start not (in this case) as 50,51.., but as 1,2...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: One way to do this would be to create a reactive object that recomputes row labels after being filtered, though I think you'd have to implement the filter yourself outside of the datatable API. Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this? It strikes me as slightly odd and with the potential to cause confusion. A row label or count that is fixed relative to the original data is a useful way for the user to keep track of observations. Incidentally the DT doc says '...change row names by providing a different character vector to `rownames`,' though you'd still need to compute this reactively.

Comment: Hey Phillip, I need the new row label to plot the observations. I am not interested in what row number was it etc. I am working with very big data, and i just wanna have a line plot of certain observations after filtering in a nice order

Answer (score 1):

The `Datatables` docs had an example of how do to this [here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html). You can use the javascript code and your `datatable` callback argument:

```
   output$tbl = renderDataTable({
                        datatable(data, filter = "top", rownames=TRUE,options = list(
                                pageLength = 300, lengthMenu = c(100,200,300,400,500,600)
                        ),
                        callback=JS("table.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
                                table.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
                                      cell.innerHTML = i+1;});}).draw();"))
                })
```

This only changes the values of the HTML displayed, the actual `rownames` of the dataset are not changed.

Comment: Hello NicE, Thanks for help!just one thing am i able to use those `rownames` as an xaxis later?can i get them out somehow into my `data.frame`?

Comment: no, but you can just create a sequence of numbers using `seq_along(input$tbl_rows_all)` and use that as an xaxis.